# Difference between $state.transitionTo() and $state.go() in Angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing, angular-ui

In AngularJS, I see sometimes we use `$state.transitionTo()` and sometimes we use `$state.go()`. Can anyone tell me how they differ and when one should be used over the other?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Are you referring to the [AngularUI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#readme)? If so, the wiki [specifies the differences](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options):

> **$state.go(to [, toParams] [, options])**
>
> Returns a **Promise** representing the state of the transition.
>
> Convenience method for transitioning to a new state. `$state.go` calls `$state.transitionTo` internally but automatically sets options to `{ location: true, inherit: true, relative: $state.$current, notify: true }`. This allows you to easily use an absolute or relative to path and specify only the parameters you'd like to update (while letting unspecified parameters inherit from the current state).
>
> ---
>
> **$state.transitionTo(to, toParams [, options])**
>
> Returns a **Promise** representing the state of the transition.
>
> Low-level method for transitioning to a new state. `$state.go()` uses `transitionTo` internally. `$state.go()` is recommended in most situations.

Comment: I found more information I need from your given links. Thank so much Brandon :)

Comment: Apparently, the values inputted in the view do not flush off if I re-trigger the view using transitionTo. Anyway we can force refresh the values/js/view? P.S. - Page reload is not an option as the view is an overlay

Answer (score 11):

[`$state.transitionTo`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statetransitiontoto-toparams--options) transite to a new state. In most cases, **you don't have to use it, you may prefer `$state.go`**.

It takes some parameters in an `options` object:

- `location`: If `true` will update the url in the location bar, if `false` will not. If string `"replace"`, will update url and also replace last history record.
- `inherit`: If `true` will inherit url parameters from current url.
- `relative` *(stateObject, default `null`)*: When transitioning with relative path (e.g '^'), defines which state to be relative from.
- `notify`: If `true`, will broadcast `$stateChangeStart` and `$stateChangeSuccess` events.
- `reload`: If `true` will force transition even if the state or params have not changed, aka a reload of the same state.

---

[`$state.go`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) is a sort of **shortcut** that call `$state.transitionTo` with default options:

- `location`: `true`
- `inherit`: `true`
- `relative`: `$state.$current`
- `notify`: `true`
- `reload`: `false`

It is more convenient as the synthax is simpler. You can call it only with a state name.

```
$state.go('home');
```