# $state.go doesn’t redirect to given path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework, states

i've got a view that's outside of my tabs, now when i try to redirect from that view to a tab i get redirected to the wrong tab. i've made a codepen to show you what i mean since i don't really know how to explain it well see the logs i create in the console

```
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform) {
     $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
            // do something
            $scope.from = fromState;
            console.log(fromState);
        })

        $scope.goBack = function(){
            console.log($scope.from.name);
            $state.go($scope.from.name);
        }

    })
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/sjerd/pen/CnLyt)

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the other answers but you have another problem.

The other problem is that, when you click on back button the state is changing to tab.volgend (which is right) but after this is going to tab.alert state... so I'm trying to figure out why is this second redirect happening.

Extract from console.log when clicking back button:
[image]

My first candidate is:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/alerts');
```

You shouldn't use ui-route with standard routing, so you should comment this line an add the next in your controller:

```
  console.log('going to default state');
  $state.go('tab.alerts');
```

### EDIT

The second transition is made by the ionic framework, I have put a breakpoint and check the callstack, check this captures:

1- first call when back is clicked:
[image]

2- The ionic framework detects a change in the url and.. fires the second transition:
[image]

I'm going to read more this framework to see if I understand why is this happening... I keep you updated.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought it could have something to do with the urlrouterprovider so i commented it out. but it didn't fix my bug

Comment: I'm on it, i started a jsfiddle which is easier to fork for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vde0yj6j/

Comment: thanks, stil haven't figured it out. it's one of the last bugs remaining in my app and it's a big one :(

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the name of the state to $state.go(), not the state object.

So $state.go($scope.from.name) should solve this for you.

Comment: yes it should but it doesn't that's my problem, I forgot to add the .name back after I tested

Comment: I had a look at your pen, and for some reason it is successfully redirecting to tab.volgend but then again redirecting to tab.alerts from there.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply use

```
$state.go('stateName', {//for stateParams}, { reload: true });
```

Comment: well try it in my code pen... it doesn't work that's my problem

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me too. Try transitionTo method, instead of go

```
$state.transitionTo($scope.from.name);
```

This worked out in my case.

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statetransitiontoto-toparams--options)

Edit : I forked your original codepen and it worked there too.. [Forked Codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HlkLt)

Comment: when I open your pen it doesn't work, tried to apply it to my project and didn't work their either, still get redirected to the alert template still thanks for the input

Comment: For those wondering, we have a question on the [difference between $state.transitionTo() and $state.go() in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21105528/531762). It should be noted that `$state.go()` is recommended in most situations.