# AngularJS Parent State, recognize Statetransition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router. I have a state called `user` which displays a list of users and another state called `user.edit` which displays a form with a submit button. It is a nested state of `user`. If the user clicks submit the state will be transfered back to `user` like that:
`$state.transitionTo('user');` I would like the Controller of the `user` state to recognize that stateTransition and update some data.

I don't know where to start looking for a solution and would be glad
 for any hint.

Comment: I think you need to use $onInit method, it will be called whenever your state is loaded. Also it is more convenient to use $state.go. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105528/difference-between-state-transitionto-and-state-go-in-angular-ui-router for difference.

Answer (score 0):

$routeChangeStart is what you are looking for !

Just take a look at the documention for $route, whenever a route change, this event will occur.

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
  //next is the next route information and current the current route.

 // you can check if its the right transition or not
});
```

You can also, while you are making the transition, trigger a custom event which will be listened by you user Controller.